# Does immutability allow values to be changed or not?

Tags: immutability

**There is a hole in my understanding of immutability.** I frequently hear that:

> immutability means a value doesn't change

...but how does a programmer handle when whatever they are modelling does actually change?

For example, in a user interface:

```
const selectedTab = 'users'
```

What if the user selects another tab, like `'sales'`? What should happen to `selectedTab`?

I **think** that the description of immutability may be incorrect, and that immutable values can change, but the values are only changed when a function is invoked. For example, the click handler on the tab could do something like

```
var selectedTab = 'users'
salesTabElement.on('click', function(event){
   ...
   selectedTab = 'sales'
})
```

Maybe there is another explanation. It seems like either:

- Many people are incorrectly stating immutability means values cannot change
- There is a way to modelling something which changes that does not involve changing the value of a variable.

**Does immutability allow values to be changed or not?**

Comment: Are you asking about javascript specifically? You also need to distinguish between the values here i.e. `'users'`, `'sales'` etc. and the `selectedTab` variable. If you need `selectedTab` to be changed then it shouldn't be immutable. It's correct to say immutable values do not change, so if you want to model this using immutable values you'd need to model the state explicitly containing a `selectedTab` field and have your updates return a new state e.g. `{selectedTab: 'users'} => {selectedTab: 'sales'}`.

Comment: I think he talks about functional programming, where you can't mutate objects. I don't think it would fit with event driven programming languages like javascript, even if someone states differently

Comment: A solution would be making `selectedTab` a `Subscription` object and emit a new string at every click. Sounds like an overkill

Comment: @lee I'm using JavaScript as an example, since it's popular and I do most of my programming there, but the question is not tagged JavaScript and the question is not about JavaScript specifically.

Comment: @Christian Yes, from what I understand (and I may be wrong here) immutability is generally used as part of FP.

Comment: Ok, are you asking about the `selectedTab` variable or the bound values? It looks like `const` prevents the variable from being rebound but doesn't make the referenced values immutable (as most values in javascript are not). If you need to change the bound value for `selectedTab`, you can't make it `const`.

Comment: @lee I'm aware of what `var` `let` and `const` so. My thinking was that immutability means I can't change the value of `selectedTab`, hence deliberately writing `const`. I do not understand the difference 'selectedTab variable vs 'the bound values'. My understanding is that selectedTab is a name being applied to some memory, which contains 'users'. Immutability (the way its commonly spoken of) would mean I am not allowed to change that memory to have a different value.

Comment: The bound values in this case are the strings `users` and `sales` you're assigning to `selectedTab`. `const` prevents you re-assigning to `selectedTab` so you should get a `TypeError` if you run the handler in your question. You can bind `const` variables to mutable values though e.g. `const o = {a: 1}; o.a = 3;`.

Comment: @lee Pardon the typo in my last comment it should have been 'I'm aware of what var let and const *d*o.' - you don't need to explain it. If immutability allows values to be changed, we can happily use `let` or `var`. But to reiterate: the question is **does immutability allow values to be changed or not?**

Comment: Immutable values cannot be mutated, and immutable variables (like using `const` for `selectedTab` in your question) cannot be re-bound. Your question seems to be about `const` variables, so no they can't be changed.

Comment: @lee My question is not about const variables, as mentioned twice already. As this doesn't seem like this is a two way or respectful conversation, I would prefer that we end it.

Comment: I'm not trying to be disrespectful but it really isn't clear what your actual question is. Immutable variables cannot be rebound, and if you change what a variable refers to, either from within a function or otherwise then it isn't immutable by definition. If you want to model state changes using immutable values you need to model your current state as a value (e.g. a record) and then return an updated state from any function that needs to act on it.

Comment: @lee what specific part of 'Does immutability allow values to be changed or not?' is unclear? I am modelling my current state for the selected tab as a value - it is a value called `selectedTab`. How can I model the state changing to a different tab being selected if I cannot change the value of `selectedTab`?

Comment: I've answered that question three times now: immutable values cannot be changed. If you want to model state changes with immutable values then don't store them in immutable variables. This means your event handlers need to return a value instead of mutating the global environment - one approach is to use a reactive streams library like rxjs.

Comment: @lee OK, so it sounds as if, per the question 'There is a way to modelling something which changes that does not involve changing the value of a variable.'. How would I go about modelling state changes (without using a library)? If you can answer that I'll mark it as accepted.